# macOS: rendering to another process' window

Tags: macos, qt, ipc, nsview, nswindow

I have a Qt application that needs to be used from a VST plugin. However embedding a Qt application into a plugin seems like an incredibly complex task (because of the QCoreApplication event loop, because the host might also use a conflicting version of Qt, and because the plugin needs to find its own set of Qt libraries).

As a workaround I'd like to render my standalone Qt application to the VST plugin's window (for which I know the HWND/NSView).
It's easy to do on Windows, but a little more tricky on macOS.

**tldr:** I've read about NSWindowSharingType / NSWindowSharingReadWrite which seems to offer what I need on macOS (rendering a process' window into another process' window), but I can't find any example using that.
Does anybody know about that and how to use it ? Or any other way that would allow me to render my Qt widgets into a NSView from a different process ?

Comment: were you able to find out a sample for NSWindowSharingReadWrite ?

Answer (score 1):

The solutions for this are quite nominal:

1. Your copy of Qt must be put into its own unique namespace - i.e. you have to build your own Qt. In a professional setting you're supposed to be doing this anyway.
2. The `QCoreApplication` event loop is fully integrated with `NSRunLoop`. You don't need to call `exec()` other than to prime the event loop: i.e. quit the event loop as soon as it is started, and let the host application do the rest. The idiom for this is:

   ```
   QTimer::singleShot(0, app, &QCoreApplication::quit);
   app->exec();
   // return to the host app here
   ```
3. The plugin can and should bundle its own Qt, either as a bundled framework, or through static linking.

You can also pass an `NSView*` to `QWindow::fromWinID`, IIRC.